# Responding to copy-paste answers of questionable validity

Tags: support, etiquette

In the below question, user Ankur posts the same comment, advocating a library, on almost all of the answers verbatim.

The problem I see is that

1. The comment is not discussing the answer it's pasted on, it's attempting to be a (poor quality) answer in and of itself.
2. It's pseudovalid as an answer, most folks I know would say advocating a library when asked for JS help is only half answering the question. The answer-providers involved also seem to think this, since they respond saying as much.
3. Copy pasting the same thing to every answer has *got* to qualify as spamming, doesn't it?

[Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

So the action I took was to flag the visible ones as unnecessary, but I am not entirely clear as to how it should be handled, nor if my assessment of the comment was valid.

Did I do this wrong? How should it be done?

Comment: Meh, nothing is quite as effective against such comments as demonstrating that it is a useless and wasteful approach.  His name does not appear on the list of project contributors, so it is not the typical project spam.

Comment: Is that to suggest I should simply ignore them then? I just want to be clear on what you're saying?

Comment: The comments were not ignored.  No additional help is required.  Technically you can flag the comment as "no longer needed" but I don't think that would be the correct approach.  Some visitors might favor a library or happen to already have a dependency on it.

Comment: They posted four of them, on the question and three answers on that same question. I would have custom flagged the comments on the answers, saying that *this same comment is already present on the question. The comments on the answers (3x) are therefor no longer needed. Please remove this comment*